# Offline-only Spreadsheets app for android?

Tags: android, offline, spreadsheet, office365, open-office

I am familiar with Google Sheets app. However, My spreadsheets automatically end up online despite my attempts to configure the app offline-only.

**I do not want my spreadsheets online, period.** - even if its only my google account that has access.

I am looking for a good reliable alternative app that is non-cloud based and free.

Comment: If someone tells you you can do everything **on** your device, ask them to enter airplane mode and show you… Sad, but almost everything is cloud-based. Be welcome to take a look at [my app list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office) – but the few candidates that might work offline have long not seen any updates I'm afraid.

Comment: There is the LibreOffice Viewer on F-Droid. The editing functionality is not there yet (only experimental feature now), but they are working on it. I would not recommend downloading any similar app from google play, since these are not made by LibreOffice.